# Finding out lambda calculus/haskell type of some example

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

Suppose that the function gets as its input two variables of different types (e.g. one variable is int in the language of C, and one variable is char in the language of C) and returns one variable that is in `Int`.

If this function is coded as Haskell or lambda calculus code, how would the function's type be?

So suppose that the function has type `Int -> (Char -> Char) -> Int`. What would this mean? Would this mean that it receives int variable as input and runs function of `(Char -> Char)` and outputs `Int` variable?

Comment: metoosFunction :: Int -> Char -> Int

Comment: "...and runs function of (char->char) and..." stop thinking procedurally if you want to learn Haskell. _You **don't** "run" functions_, you rather evaluate their result for certain inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A type of `Int -> (Char -> Char) -> Int` would mean the function accepts an `Int` and a function of type `Char -> Char` as input, and outputs an `Int`.

The function doesn't have to actually *use* its inputs per se.  For example,

```
meetoosFunction :: Int -> (Char -> Char) -> Int
meetoosFunction _ _ = 42

*Main Data.Char> meetoosFunction 1 toUpper
42
```